# XPages ValuePicker Limited to 1000

Tags: xpages, picker

I use valuePicker and DojoListTextBox design element. If i have more than 1.000 values this valuepicker lists at most 1.000 records. How to increase that limitation? I just want it to list how many values i have.

```xml
<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker10" for="djTextList1"
    dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerCheckbox">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker caseInsensitive="false">
            <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                try {var viewName="viewName";
                var dbname = new Array("", sessionScope.personel_db_Path);
                return @Trim(@Unique(@DbColumn(dbname, viewName,1).sort()));}
                catch(e) { print(e)}
            }]]></xe:this.valueList>
        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

Any suggestion is important,
Cumhur Ata

Comment: @DbColumn can only return 64k of data.

Comment: Ha, well spotted, Sven. That explains the problem

Comment: There is no limit of 1000 entries. I just tested it with 2000 - all are visible. Sven is probably right with the 64K limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the maxRowCount Dojo attribute so your valuePicker looks like this:

```
<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker10" for="djTextList1" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerCheckbox">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker caseInsensitive="false">
            <xe:this.valueList>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    try {var viewName="viewName";
                    var dbname = new Array("", sessionScope.personel_db_Path);
                    return @Trim(@Unique(@DbColumn(dbname, viewName,1).sort()));}
                    catch(e) { print(e)}
                }]]>
            </xe:this.valueList>
        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="maxRowCount" value="10000"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

Comment: I have changed my dataProvider of valuePicker then my code looks like this
<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker10" for="DosyaKarsiTaraf" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerCheckbox"><xe:this.dataProvider><xe:dominoViewValuePicker databaseName="#{javascript:return sessionScope.kontak_db_Path;}" labelColumn="$KurumKodu">
<xe:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "(viewKarsiTaraf)";}]]></xe:this.viewName></xe:dominoViewValuePicker></xe:this.dataProvider><xe:this.dojoAttributes><xp:dojoAttribute name="maxRowCount" value="10000"></xp:dojoAttribute></xe:this.dojoAttributes></xe:valuePicker>

Comment: I am still stuck with 1000 records